# Entity framework core remove all the data related to an object

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I started a project in ASP.Net Core, I created an object which I introduced in a db context. This object has a property which is another object and this has a property which is another object. It sounds very confusing but I'm going to put  these classes below to make it clearer.

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {
        Days = new List<DayComponent>();

        DateTime day = DateTime.Now;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bool ok = false;
            do
            {
                if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                {
                    day = day.AddDays(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = true;
                    Days.Add(new DayComponent(day));
                    day = day.AddDays(1);
                }
            } while (!ok);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<DayComponent> Days { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class DayComponent
{
    public DayComponent()
    {
        Hours = new List<HourComponent>();
    }

    public DayComponent(DateTime day)
    {
        if (day == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(day));
        }
        Day = day;

        Hours = new List<HourComponent>();

        Hours.Add(new HourComponent { Hour = 9.00F });
    }

    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    public List<HourComponent> Hours { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class HourComponent
{
    public HourComponent()
    {
        Status = StatusComponent.Liber;
    }

    public float Hour { get; set; }

    public StatusComponent Status { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public enum StatusComponent
{
    Free = 0,
    Busy
}
```

And here is my code for dbcontext:

```
public class ArushiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ArushiUser>
{
    public ArushiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ArushiDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DayComponent> Days { get; set; }

    public DbSet<HourComponent> Hours { get; set; }
}
```

So, my problem is that when I remove a Schedule object from database ,as in the code which I'll post below, it only removes the Schedule and makes the ScheduleId from Days database null, but I want to delete all the data related to that schedule( its days and its hours ).

```
var scheduleToRemove = _dbContext.Schedule.Where(s => s.Id == user.Schedule.Id)
                        .Include(p => p.Days)
                        .Include("Days.Hours")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

So, how can I delete all the data related to a Schedule object?

Comment: Use foreign keys on every table referenced and also set cascade update & delete attributes for those columns. "A foreign key with cascade delete means that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted."

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to make like you said.